# SwiftUI TextField loses focus inside List

Tags: swiftui-list

I am still new to SwiftUI and I can't solve this issue. I am displaying a list of products and I've put a TextField at the end in order to add a product to the list. My goal is to keep the focus on the TextField whenever the user submits a new product and so far it works with one exception. Whenever the list is empty, the focus does not go back to the TextField and the user has to click on it again. As soon as there is at least one product, the focus is working as intended.

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var products: [String] = []
    @State var newProductName = ""
    @FocusState private var isFieldFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(products, id: \.self) { product in
                Text(product)
            }
            
            TextField("...", text: $newProductName)
                .focused($isFieldFocused)
                .onSubmit {
                    if (newProductName.count > 0 && newProductName != "...") {
                        products.append(newProductName)
                        newProductName = ""
                        isFieldFocused = true
                    }
                }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.onAppear` modifier to explicitly set the focus when the view appears, ensuring that the `TextField` is focused even when the list is empty.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var products: [String] = []
  @State var newProductName = ""
  @FocusState private var isFieldFocused: Bool
  var body: some View {
    List {
      // your above code
    }
    .onAppear {
      if products.isEmpty {
        isFieldFocused = true 
      }
    }
  }
}
```